# Laravel - Run scheduled task only if same previous task has finished

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was wondering if Laravel has a built in function to only run a scheduled task if the previous has finished.

I have a need to run a specific task every few seconds, but the task relies on querying another host that may at some point lose connection.

There are a couple of ways I thought about doing this, if there isn't:

1. Having the task just put the job into the queue
2. Having a flag saved (Either as a file or in the db), that is set at the start of the task, and unset at the finish.

Just hoping the task scheduler has something built in before I go down either of those routes ...

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer in the Docs :D

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

excerpt:

**Preventing Task Overlaps**

By default, scheduled tasks will be run even if the previous instance of the task is still running. To prevent this, you may use the withoutOverlapping method:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping();
```

In this example, the `emails:send` Artisan command will be run every minute if it is not already running. The `withoutOverlapping` method is especially useful if you have tasks that vary drastically in their execution time, preventing you from predicting exactly how long a given task will take.